# Ag-grid text filter for filtering across an entire array of strings

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid

- I am using a Angular Material select with multiple options.
- Every time an option is selected or unselected, I'm calling an option
  to filter the data in the table and show only those rows which are
  selected.

This is the code for the mat-select.

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="RequestID" id = "filter-check-box" multiple>
    <mat-option (onSelectionChange) = "RequestIDCheckboxFilter($event, RequestID)" 
 *ngFor="let RequestID of RequestIDArray" [value]="RequestID">{{RequestID}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

- This is the definition of RequestIDArray : `RequestIDArray: string[] = ['REQ001', 'REQ002', 'REQ003', 'REQ004'];`

And this is the definition of the RequestIDCheckboxFilter function. ReqIDFilter is the array where I'm storing the values which are checked currently. :

```typescript
RequestIDCheckboxFilter(event, text: string) {
  var CheckboxFilterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance("requestID");
  if(event.isUserInput) {
    var index = this.ReqIDFilter.indexOf(text);
    if(index == -1) {
      this.ReqIDFilter.push(text);
    } 
    else {
      this.ReqIDFilter.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < this.ReqIDFilter.length; i++) {
    CheckboxFilterComponent.setModel({
      type: "equals",
      filter: this.ReqIDFilter[i]
    })
  }

  this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
}
```

When I do this, I'm only able to see one of the rows even if multiple options are selected. Say, if REQ001 and REQ002 are selected, only the row with REQ001 is visible. I have also tried using a for loop inside the setModel but that gives an error. Is there any way I can filter the table for all the values in the array?

Edit : I'm using the community version of ag-grid.

Comment: are you using the community or enterprise version of ag-grid?

Comment: Community version. I'll just update that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with the `text filter`.
In your loop you overwrite the filter model with every iteration.

See also [ag-grid gridApi.setFilterModel() model with multiple conditions [angular6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174160/ag-grid-gridapi-setfiltermodel-model-with-multiple-conditions-angular6)

The enterprise version has something called [`Set Filter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/) which does what you want.

So I see the following options

- buy the enterprise version (which is quite expensive)
- try to create a custom filter
- filter your grid's datasource and not the grid directly.

EDIT: there is a trial version of the enterprise version available so you can test, if the set filter is the right tool for your need.

Maybe [Does ag-grid have an api to filter multiple checkbox values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452147/does-ag-grid-have-an-api-to-filter-multiple-checkbox-values?rq=1) helps?